# How to read a tweet that contains a curly apostrophe (’)

Tags: r

I am reading tweets in the following format:

```
545253503963516928|Wed Dec 17 16:25:40 +0000 2014|Massachusetts Pharmacy Owners Arrested in Meningitis Deaths http://xxxxxxxxx
545235402156937217|Wed Dec 17 15:13:44 +0000 2014|For First Time, Treatment Helps Patients With Worst Kind of Stroke, Study Says http://xxxxxxxxx
```

The code I'm using is

```
msn  <- read.table(file=".../msnhealthnews.txt", 
                   sep="|", 
                   header = FALSE, 
                   quote="", 
                   fill=TRUE, 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                   numerals ="no.loss",
                   encoding = "UTF-8")
```

There is a tweet that has a curly apostrophe:

```
You’re Already Losing Your Mind:  http://on-msn.com/w0LiSx
```

This tweet is being read as follows:

```
"You\u0092re Already Losing Your Mind:  http://on-msn.com/w0LiSx"
```

How I can ensure that the tweet is read correctly? I thought that setting `encoding = "UTF-8"` would take care of this.

Comment: Please define "correctly". You seem to want magical things to happen. Magic, sadly, isn't real.

Comment: Please use encoding = utf-8

Comment: try running through the other encodings? Once I found that UTF-10 worked for me

Comment: @hrbrmstr: by correctly, I mean that `You're` should be read as such and not as `You\u0092re`  I want to be able determine the total number of characters in each tweet using nchar(msn$V3). However, this throws up an error when it encounters `You\u0092re`